# Cannot replace the file name using Angular.js ng-file-upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am trying to rename the file name after uploading the file using Angular.js `ng-file-upload`. But what is happening in my case when I am removing `ngf-min-height="400" ngf-resize="{width: 400, height:400}"` properties. I am providing my code below:

```
<input type="file"  data-size="lg" name="bannerimage" id="imagefile1"  ng-model="file" ngf-pattern="image/*" accept="image/*"  ngf-max-size="2MB" ngf-min-height="400" ngf-resize="{width: 400, height:400}"   custom-on-change="uploadFile"  ngf-select="onFileSelect($file);" >
```

My controller side code is given below:

```
$scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
         fileURL=$files;
         $scope.imageData='';
    }
var file=fileURL;
var today=(Math.random() * new Date().getTime()).toString(36).replace(/\./g, '');
var newpath=today+"_"+ file.name;
file.name=newpath;
```

In the above code I am adding a random number to file name and replacing it. In this case it's coming properly, but if I am removing `ngf-min-height="400" ngf-resize="{width: 400, height:400}"` from file input like below.

```
<input type="file"  data-size="lg" name="bannerimage" id="imagefile1"  ng-model="file" ngf-pattern="image/*" accept="image/*"  ngf-max-size="2MB"   custom-on-change="uploadFile"  ngf-select="onFileSelect($file);" >
```

In this case I cannot replace the new file name and I don't need to restrict the file `height and width`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Upload Service of ng-file-upload has a method for this.
Here is an example:

```
$scope.$watch('dropFile', function () {
    uploadFile($scope.dropFile);
});

function uploadFile(file) {
  if (!file) {
    return;
  }

  file = Upload.rename(file, "newName.ext");

  Upload.upload({
        url: <api url for upload>,
        data: {file: file}
    }).then(function (resp) {
      //successful
    }, function (resp) {
        //error
    }, function (evt) {
       //progress
    });
}
```

Comment: nice! I was trying to find something like that. thank you

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
<input type="file"  data-size="lg" name="bannerimage" id="imagefile1"  ng-model="file" accept="image/*" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files[0]);" >

$scope.onFileSelect =function(file){
    filename = 'jihin.' + file.name.split(".")[1];
    var imgFile = new File([file], filename, {type:file.type});
    console.log(imgFile);
};
```

Comment: ok,i will try this but  its ok with `ngf-min-height="400" ngf-resize="{width: 400, height:400}"` when i am removing this its not happening.Why?it need to be resolved.

Comment: use ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files[0]);" insted of ngf-select @satya